# Multi language speech translation

Tags: azure-speech

Can Azure cognitive services  assist to translate multi languages (e.g. japanese,chinese and spanish) in 1 audio clips to English in text form.
Is the multi translation for a single file is possible?

Answer (score 0):

[Video Indexer (VI)](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/video-indexer/video-indexer-overview#audio-insights) supports [multi language identification and transcription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/video-indexer/multi-language-identification-transcription) (public preview) for cases where speakers do not overlap.
if the translator was recorded on a separate channel, VI supports split channel conversations detection and transcription where speech overlap is supported.

Once the multi-language transcription is in place, the customer can translate it to multiple different languages.

[image]